# ESXi 5 doesn't autostart VMs

Tags: boot, esxi

I just started using ESXi 5, the free version.  Everything seems to run great, and everything is on the HCL.

My only issue is that the VMs I've selected to auto-start on start-up aren't starting up at all. I found a vague reference to this on the VMWare page indicating that it's a bug.  Is there a workaround I can employ?  For example, a cron job to start up VMs that aren't started?  They don't need to start immediately, but starting them at a reasonable interval would be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Auto Start bug ([VMware Community)](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/03/free-esxi-hypervisor-auto-start-breaks-with-50-update-1.html) introduced with 5.0 Update 1, which broke the VM Auto Start feature on the free version of ESXi. VMware released the ESXi patch "ESXi500-201207001" on July 12, 2012 which includes the fix.

You can download the patch from here: [Download](https://hostupdate.vmware.com/software/VUM/OFFLINE/release-346-20120706-638484/ESXi500-201207001.zip)

You can review the bulletins and image profiles included with the patch from here: 
[VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2019107)

Auto Starting is back:)

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much!  Just a note to others that may not have done this before, applying the patch was easily done with: `esxcli software vib install --depot /full/path/to/zip`.